# Surrounding every character with <span> changes word wrap behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a webpage where I can style each character in some element individually (by wrapping each character in each text node in a `<span>`). However, with the other styles that I have on the element, simply wrapping each letter like this is changing the appearance of the text, either by wrapping words early or by inserting visible whitespace in the beginning of lines.

```js
function spanEachCharacter(el) {
 if (el.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
 {
  var text = el.textContent;
  var html = "";
  [...text].forEach(function(c) {
   html += `<span>${escapeHTML(c)}</span>`;
  });
  
  var node = document.createElement("span");
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(node, el);
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  node.outerHTML = html;
 }
 else
 {
  Array.from(el.childNodes).forEach(function(child) {
   spanEachCharacter(child);
  });
 }
}

function escapeHTML(text) {
 var textEl = document.createElement("span");
 textEl.textContent = text;
 return textEl.innerHTML;
}

spanEachCharacter(document.getElementById("text2"));
```

```css
div {
  background: lightPink;
  width: 235px;
  
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">This is some filler text. Boy, oh boy, do I love filler text. Yes, this filler text couldn't possibly be any better.</div>
<br>
<div id="text2">This is some filler text. Boy, oh boy, do I love filler text. Yes, this filler text couldn't possibly be any better.</div>
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the `overflow-wrap: break-word` style not recognizing words once they're split across `<span>` elements. How would I be able to wrap each letter in a span while keeping the same appearance as before?

EDIT: I was able to figure out that the simple act of wrapping a character in a `<span>` tag increases its width by an imperceptible amount, about 1/10 of a pixel. Here is a comparison picture of a short phrase vs. that same phrase with each character (except the whitespace) wrapped in a `<span>` tag.

[image: This infuriates me to no end.]

Funny thing is, this only seems to show up in Chrome and Chrome-based browsers. Is this a rendering bug or something?

Comment: One instant improvement is to check that you only don't wrap whitespace characters.

Comment: @SamiHult That doesn't change anything. I even had it in a previous edit of this question and took it out because I realized it didn't change how it looked.

Comment: All right. I think that the explanation why those small changes occur is that the browser tries to render the text as readable as possible (there are many algorithms, partly controllable via browser-specific css) and take font's kerning data into account. If you render spans, they will laid out as inline passages and since there are technically no character pairs, the kerning doesn't work the same way.

Comment: @SamiHult Ah, that makes at least a bit of sense. I assume, then, that whatever font renderer used by Firefox and Edge *do* take character pairs across adjacent span elements into account? This doesn't happen in either of those browsers.

Comment: For real insight, we would need some inside/expert knowledge.

Comment: As soon as possible, I'd love to know how to *fix* this behavior. I don't care too much about the width of the content anymore, but I'd at least love to be able to fix the initial whitespace of some lines.